# pdf files in java cant add header or margin?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

any body know why my header or margin wont work/generate on page? it only generates the pdf with the paragraph saying "hello neck"

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.*;

public class Report {



    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception
     {


        try{
            File temp = File.createTempFile("tempfile", ".pdf");


                OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(temp);
                Document document  = new Document();

                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
                document.open();
                document.addHeader("header1", "this is my header file");
                document.setMargins(50, 50, 100, 100);
                document.add(new Paragraph("hello neck"));
                document.close();
                file.close();

                if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    Desktop dtop = Desktop.getDesktop();

                    if (dtop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN)) {
                        String temp2 = temp.getPath();      
                        dtop.open(new File(temp2));
                    }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong kind of header.  That's for meta-information rather than page headers & footers.

Think "content-type" rather than "page x of y".

```
//these two lines of code are identical
document.addHeader("a", "b");
document.add(new Header("a", "b"));
```

`Header` inherits from `Meta`, which handles author/title/etc/etc.  Header is for arbitrary strings that don't fall into one of the standard values.

Also, you can only change metadata until you call document.open().  Afterwards, any changes are ignored (or do they throw... I don't recall)

But you want headers and footers.  The traditional way of handling that is via a `PdfPageEvent`'s OnEndPage function.  If you inherit from `PdfPageEventHelper`, it has already stubbed out all the functions in the `PdfPageEvent` interface, so you just need to override the one you want.  Handy.

In your OnEndPage you'll want to use a `ColumnText` object to write text into the PdfContentByte provided.